Centripetal motion inside centripetal motion
I don't know which one of the 2 methods I created for this problem is correct:

Consider a girl is on the following ride. The tea cups spin around the central tea pot at an angular velocity of 2 radians/s. The tea cups are 2m from the centre.

A girl in a tea cup begins spinning herself as shown below. The tips of her fingers are 1m from the centre of her body, and she spins at 1 radian/second.

Determine the centripetal acceleration of her right hand’s (green) finger tips, in the position depicted above.

Method 1: Treat it as 1 Circular Motion
Since she is spinning and the teacup is spinning, find the speed relative to the ground that her hand is moving at. Then sub it into the centripetal acceleration formula.
$$a_c = \frac{v^2}{r}$$
$$a_c = \frac{(2m \times 3 + 1m \times 1)^2}{3}$$
$$a_c = 16.3ms^{-2}$$
Method 2: Treat it as 2 Circular motions
We can find the centripetal acceleration of the hand about the girl and add it to the centripetal acceleration of the hand about the teapot.
$$a_{total} = a_{\text{about girl}} + a_{\text{about teacup}}$$
$$a_c = \frac{(1m \times 1)^2}{1} + \frac{(3m \times 2)^2}{2}$$
$$a_c = 19ms^{-2}$$
I'm not sure which, if either, method is correct. I feel like the 2nd method is wrong since the velocity of the arm about the teacup is not $3m \times 2$, that's only what the girl's body is at. Her arm is further from the center than that.

This diagram could be much clearer... I think it is disrespectful towards the student to provide such a poor diagram when it's so crucial for understanding what's requested of him.

This is a fun question, but don't put values in. Have the size $R$ ride (cup) rotate at $\omega_0$ ($\omega_1$), and point out the principle where you are stuck. I would analyze it in a frame rotating at $\Omega = \omega_0$, where the centrifugal (Coriolis) for handle the position (velocity) dependent contributions to keep you fixed in the cup performing uniform circular motion.

On second read, I reject this problem's formulation. Why is the girl spinning? The cup is designed to spin, and that adds unneeded complexity. So I'd say "The cup spins: what is the force ($f$) from the seat back  on the rider ($m$)? (20 points, 1 minute).

The first method is incorrect since the motion of the girl's hand is not circular motion.
The second method is correct in principle. Relative accelerations can be added as vectors (just as relative velocities or relative displacements can be added). So you need to add the hand's acceleration relative to the girl to the girl's acceleration relative to the centre. At the instant shown, since the girl's hand, the girl and the centre of the ride line up, the two accelerations are in the same direction, so you can just add their magnitudes.
Note, however, that when calculating the girl's acceleration relative to the centre, the correct radius to use is $2$ m not $3$ m (if we assume that the girl is in the centre of a teacup and that "The tea cups are $2$ m from the centre" means that the centre of each tea cup is $2$ m from the centre of the ride).

Ok. But for her acceleration relative to the centre, although her body is 2m from the teapot, her hand itself is 3m. Why do we not use 3m then? Is her hand not doing UCM 3m from the cup?

@JohnHon The motion of the girl's hand is not uniform circular motion because if you trace the path of her hand (relative to the ground) it is not a circle.
